Episode from a CSI type show where kid drowns in toy submarine
I know this is super vague, but it's all I can recall.
It was about someone (I believe male) trying (possibly succeeding) to kill someone who sold one of those cheap back-of-comic toys, it was like, a cardboard submarine or something like that. He wanted to kill him because when he was a kid, his friend (I think a girl, could be wrong) said: 

Oh don't worry, we can trust it! its from (insert guys name here) he would never lie to us! 

But then the kid drowned in the fake sub when it sank. It was a crime show, like Bones, CSI, Law and Order, or Cold Case. I don't remember which one, but Cold Case seems like a good bet to me.
Can anyone identify this episode?
EDIT: Looking more into it, I'm fairly sure it's actually NOT Cold Case though I'm unsure about the others. It was an American show from recent years. I do vaguely recall the victim's name being Laughy or Laffy, or some variation, but I could be wrong.

So I'm assuming this was an American show from recent years?

Yeah, no question on that, i do vaguely recall the victims name being laughy or laffy, or some variation, but i could be wrong.

This is the 2007 CSI:NY episode Child's Play (Season 4, Episode 11), where a joke shop owner called Laughing Larry is the victim:

Years ago when comics still did advertisements for toys and practical jokes Larry advertised his products himself. Usually to the disappointment of children who spent their money on junk. The perp as a child along with his best friend want to buy a supposed submarine that was advertised in the back of one such comic, but when they got it one of the two was dismayed to see that it was just a bunch of cardboard, not likely to take them on an underwater adventure like Larry said it would. His friend still wanted to believe and when the sub was built used it to set out into a small lake, the cardboard vessel soon sank and with it the kid inside who couldn't swim. 

As you described, his friend says the sub would work "because Laughing Larry had said it would". Here's a clip from the episode (of a man smoking a joke cigar from the shop before it explodes):




Yes! Thank you so much, I've been trying to remember this episode for YEARS, I guess I combined "Laughing" and "Larry" into "Laffy", I honestly didn't remember any other part besides that last one, I guess the sadness of the kid drowning just really stuck out to me. There are so many of these crime shows, i expected this to take days, if ever.
